# On the size of two integrals

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A=\int_0^1 x^x dx, B= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (xy)^{xy} dxdy$, which of the following is true: $A>B, A=B$ or $A<B$.

Answer (score 1):

let $xy=t$,
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{0}^{1}(xy)^{xy}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{dy}{y}\int_{0}^{1}(xy)^{xy}d(xy)\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{dy}{y}\int_{0}^{y}t^tdt=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{y}t^tdt\right)d\ln{y}\\
&=\ln{y}\cdot\int_{0}^{y}t^tdt|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}y^y\ln{y}dy=-\int_{0}^{1}y^y\ln{y}dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}y^ydy
\end{align}

because
$$\int_{0}^{1}y^y(1+\ln{y})dy=y^y|_{0}^{1}=0$$
so
$$-\int_{0}^{1}y^y\ln{y}dy=\int_{0}^{1}y^ydy$$

mark:we  have
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{-qx}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{q^n}{(n+1)^n}$$